# Заставить браузер доверять сайту без httpS

Tags: html, http, https, http-заголовки

Получаю видео на одном сайте с другого. Оба сайта мои. Ссылка со второго сайта бонально вставляется в тег video:

```
<video><source src="http://2site.com/vid1.mp4" type="video/mp4;"></video>
```

В результате выдает ошибку:

```
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

Суть вроде понятна - сайт с которого получаю видео использует http вместо https. Можно конечно поставить https через CloudFlare например. Но нужно ли такое делать(зачем), или можно как-то заставить браузер брать видео, не парясь о том что там передается что-то секретное, с сайта на http?

Comment: Делать нужно. Заставить нельзя.

Comment: @andreymal Благодарю. Странно что такой возможности не оставлено. Может подскажете почему так? (Уже, из любознательности чисто)

Comment: Потому что небезопасно. И дело не только в секретах, но и, например, в том, что постороннее лицо сможет без https подменить ваше видео на какое-нибудь своё видео с целью напропагандировать что-нибудь смотрящим его пользователям, например